# Function not working after running it 1 time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's the fiddle of exactly what I'm doing

http://jsfiddle.net/9MCqB/

Essentially, I want to inline-edit items, and save them via AJAX.. I added a function called `select(name)` which creates a SELECT element and adds the name + ID which later gets populated with the `options(name, value, selectElement)` function. The HTLM should be replaced when I click EDIT.

It works fine when I attempt to use `select()` only 1 time. When I try to apply it to the other fields, however, it gives me:

```
TypeError: select is not a function
days = select("day");
```

I've read other questions thoroughly (maybe I missed the one), but I don't think I have bad syntax, unclosed HTML or JS, or am overwriting the function.

Any ideas? Thanks ahead of time

Code:

```
// create select field
select = function(name) {
  s = "<select></select>";
  select = $(s).attr("name", name).attr("id", name);
  return select;
}

// add options to select
options = function(name, value, selectElement) {
  o = "<option></option>";
  option = $(o).attr("value", value).html(name);
  s = $(selectElement).append(option);
  return s;
}
```

Comment: without even going through your entire code, it seems to me like you're "shadowing" select by reassigning the select variable in the select function. Either rename the function or rename the variable which you return. And even if it doesn't solve your problem it's good practice. Or at the very least put a `var` in front of the second select so you make it local to the scope.

Comment: Oh wow! Thank's for the quick response. I tried putting var before the variable and it works! Thanks a lot, I highly appreciate it :)

Comment: @damusix: I recommend you run your Javascript programs through a linting program such as JSHint.